# Ubuntu 18.04 WiFi range problem (Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth)

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, lenovo

I hope all of you are well.

Please bear with me since I am a Ubuntu debutant and I need some help. 
I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Lenovo Ideapad using a Live USB. My laptop was initially running Windows 10 but I completely overwrote the Windows partition, as I no longer have a need for it. However, I seem to have a problem with the WiFi connection. While it does work, it only works when I am standing over the router, with quality 23/70 when I run `iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'`. So here is the output when I run `sudo lshw -C network` :

`*-network

       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: 1c:39:47:ea:a4:5a
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1204000-b1204fff memory:b1200000-b1203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 99
       serial: 84:ef:18:8e:63:2c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-37-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=10.0.0.84 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:127 memory:b1100000-b1101fff`

With advice from other answers, I tried to check whether there is a block on the wifi port by running `rfkill list all` and here is the output

`0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

Showing that there is no block at all. One final thing I tried is to manually try to download the drivers from Intel (I downloaded      `iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30.14.0.tgz` from [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-io/wireless-networking.html) and placed them in the /lib/firmware directory but that did nothing either.

I'm hoping if anyone could help me, I would appreciate it a lot. Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be specific to your issue with the wireless card, but is generally a good idea. Have you updated the firmware for your laptop? 
If you know the model of your laptop (for example I have an old Thinkpad T440p that I was using until recently) then see if you can go to Lenovo's site and find the firmware update files. 
Better yet, see if you can run `fwupdmgr get-devices` in terminal and see what devices you have that are update-able.